# Bash in Conemu is overlapping lines

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, conemu

When I start nano/vi or a program that normally clears the screen then I can still see the command line. That means that the terminal is not cleared. If I scroll with the arrow keys the lines disappears.

Here is a image of what I mean. Nano is still open and the file "ohoho" has only the word succeed in it but I can see the lines from the terminal and the line that started nano and the result of the "ls" command before.

[image]

I don´t really know how to fix that. I also tried oh-my-zsh and I have the same problems.

EDIT: I know that the newconsole command is not written correctly. I only did that to show my problem. And that overlaping problem doesn´t only happen with nano or vi. This happens with nearly every program as you can see in this image where I quit "top" and the header of "top" is still there. And "clear" does the same problem. The cursor and line jumps to the top but the old lines are not cleared. But "echo -e '\0033\0143'" works and clears the screen correctly.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adbuS.png)

Comment: 1. `-newconsole` is badly written `-new_console` switch. 2. Anyway it has no sense in cygwin/msys. 3. Unless you are using connector, you have report the bug to nano/vi authors.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://superuser.com/users/585757/peter-sander and http://superuser.com/users/585766/user1058712.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?